# Organizing systemd services

Tags: linux, systemd

I have several systemd service/timer units for various applications I've written. I want to be able to organize them under a label so I can quickly see all the service/timer units I have installed on each of my servers. To be clear, I don't want to group them under a target, because they all start with different timers and conditions, and some may be disabled on certain servers.

I want to be able to run a command as such:

```bsh
Welcome to Server #1
>> systemd list-units --label=discord
deiga-discordbot.service
deiga-discordbot.timer
catto-discordbot.service
catto-discordbot.timer
discord-cleaner.service
```

```
Welcome to Server #2
>> systemd list-units --label=discord
deiga-discordbot.service
deiga-discordbot.timer
raptus.service
raptus.timer
discord-cleaner.service
sync-db.service
```

Comment: How about `systemctl list-units "*discord*"`?

Comment: That would list ALL units with specifier "discord". What if I have a service where the title isn't discord? What if I want a tag called "my-web" with services like `discord-bot1` and `web-scraper`? I've updated my question to be more clear in that regard.

Comment: I am not aware of anything like a tagging concept in systemd. In my opinion, you need to make do with the unit name. You could work with dependencies, but from your description, that's not an option. You could try to (mis)use namespaces or slices, but they only work for units that control processes, not timers.